# Find command with -ctime +0 for testing

Tags: find

The following command will delete directories and sub directories that are older then 100 days:

```
find /var/tmp -type d -ctime +100 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But actually I want to perform the test to verify if the command will remove all directories.

So I set `-ctime +0` (in order to perform remove directories that old then 0 days)

```
find /var/tmp -type d -ctime +0 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But the find command did not remove the directories.

How can I change the `-ctime` in order to perform the test?

Comment: What do you mean by the _age of a directory_? `-ctime` is _change time_, that's for the time the status (data or metadata (permission, ownerships or other  attributes)) of the file was last changed.  Use `-mtime` for modification time (data changed which for a directory means entries added, removed or renamed (which I can't imagine it being what you want either). `-ctime +0` is for at least 1 day old. Use `-prune` after your `rm`.

Answer (score 2):

The `man` page of `find` says this about `-ctime`:

```
-ctime n
       File's status was last changed n*24 hours ago.  See the comments
       for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation
       of file status change times.
```

and this about `-atime`:

```
-atime n
       File was last accessed n*24 hours ago.  When  find  figures  out
       how  many  24-hour  periods  ago the file was last accessed, any
       fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to
       have been accessed at least two days ago.
```

So you should expect `-ctime 1` to remove files that were changed 1 day ago or more based on the rounding, and you should set it to `-ctime +-1` to get the effect you want.

To prevent `/var/tmp` itself from being deleted itself also specify `-mindepth 1` and while experimenting always first print out the directories `find` is going to work on:

```
 find /var/tmp -mindepth 1 -type d -ctime +-1  -print
```

before doing the destructive:

```
  find /var/tmp -mindepth 1 -type d -ctime +-1 -exec rm -rf {} +
```

( I would use `+` instead of `\;` no need to invoke rm multiple times. (Alternatively you could look at using `-delete` instead of using `-exec rm....` but in that case `find` would need to remove the files under those directories as well, while leaving those directly under `/var/tmp`)

Comment: another quastion - find /var/tmp -type d -ctime +100 -exec rm -rf {} \;
command deleted also the tmp dir under /var - how to avoid this , and why it remove the tmp under /var ?

Comment: @maihabunash you might want to include `-mindepth 1` or if there are no "hidden" directories in `/var/tmp` use `find /var/tmp/* ....` The directory gets changed every time something gets added to it e.g.

Answer (score 0):

This command remove the directories created in the last day.

```
find /var/tmp -type d -ctime -1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```